# READ or WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE permission : WHY NO ERROR?

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

Yes, I am not getting error.

I had defined permissions in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am picking up images from External Storage using [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) and Its working fine.

I am confused because its working even I did not wrote any code to take run time permission of External Storage.

Tested Device Information:
- Samsung J8, OS - Andorid 9 Pie, 
- Nexus 5X Emulator = OS - Andorid 9 Pie

Is there any changes in permission policy?  Why its is working?

Comment: on which device/emulator you are testing your application ?

Comment: 1. Samsung J8, OS - Andorid 9 Pie, 2. Nexus 5X Emulator = OS - Andorid 9 Pie

Comment: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` not required because its does not write anything on external storage . Basically it uses `getCacheDir` to write i guess . For rest you can check the source code of this library..

Comment: look at the library issue : https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/421

Comment: So you want to say that cache folder doesn't required any permission? @ADM

Comment: Yeah it doesn't AFAIK..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/421#issuecomment-514500481) I found answer in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#ExternalStoragePermissions):

> Beginning with `Android 4.4 (API level 19)`, reading or writing files
>   in your app's private external storage directory — accessed using
>   `getExternalFilesDir()` — does not require the
>   **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** or **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permissions.

Its not required for my project because my minimum API level is 19.

> So if your app supports `Android 4.3 (API level 18)` and lower, and
>   you want to access only the private external storage directory, you
>   should declare that the permission be requested only on the lower
>   versions of Android by adding the `maxSdkVersion` attribute:
>
> ```
> <manifest ...>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
>                      android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
>     ...
> </manifest>
> ```

Thank you.